# How to get the line "source devel/setup.bash" to run after every time you catkin_make?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have "source devel/setup.bash" added to my bashrc file, but sometimes, if I create a new package and then compile it for the first time with "catkin_make", then I find I need to open a new terminal in order to run the package because the terminal I already have open needs to source devel/setup.bash again.

Does anyone know how to get "source devel/setup.bash" to run every time I do catkin_make?  Or otherwise how to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117801/how-to-get-the-line-%22source-devel/setup.bash%22-to-run-after-every-time-you-catkin_make?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Either you must run the above source command each time you open a new terminal window
2. or add it to your .bashrc file as follows.

echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

I found the above instruction from this website:
https://github.com/MST-Robotics/MST_ROS_Catkin_Packages/wiki/New-Member-Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [urthkakao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9441/urthkakao/) with karma: 108 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2016-11-06**:
or

```
catkin_make  &  source devel/setup.sh
```

or even set up an alias for that e.g. in your ~/.bashrc

```
alias catkin_make_and_source='catkin_make & source devel/setup.sh'
```